# Is the way that VDS(max) is calculated correct?

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, current, resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHrgpN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is also the resistance of the Mosfet which is equal to 0.25(Ohm) I just didn't know how to add it to the circuit. We're gonna call it **Rdson**.

**First question says: Calculate Ids that passes through the transistor.**

Vcc - rIds - Rdson x Ids = 0

Ids = 12/ (0.25 + 1.25) = **8 A**

**Second question says: Calculate VDS(max)**

Vds = Ids(r + Rdson) = 8(1.5) = 12v

That's what I don't understand. Why the book included r in calculating VDS? Isn't it supposed to be:

**Vds = Ids x r**

Did the book make a mistake here?

Also, is VDS(max) the same as normal VDS?

*My problem:* How VDS(max) is calculated in this circuit? Is the way the book solved it correct?

Comment: Only you can answer this because only you have the book.

Comment: What book? Link to it. "The internal resistance fo the MOSFET" seems garbled at best ... internal between which pins?

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's what it says. There is no more available information in the book more than what I provided in the post. Also, the book is in Arabic.

Comment: *VCC = 12*, but in the schematic it says +15 V, what is it? Stop confusing everyone, remove the schematic pic. and draw a new one. Also **units**: *VCC = 12* nope, it should be: VCC = 12 **V**, same: Rdson = 0.25 **Ohms**. *Rson is the resistance you see on the circuit (which has 1.8k instead)* OK, I give up, this is too much of a mess. Please be consistent instead of stating A and then later oh, no it's actually B.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie That circuit you see isn't from the book but it's wired exactly like in the book but the values are different that's all. The values I wrote override the values in the picture. So any calculating should be done with my values, not on the circuit. That's all.

Comment: In the equivalent game of rock, paper, scissors.... "schematic" beats "words" every time. Get used to it i.e. don't post a circuit and then correct/amend it in text - that is asking for trouble.

Comment: Get Horowitz & Hill "The Art of Electronics" and make that your book instead..

Comment: @rdtsc Done....

Comment: New circuit: hmm, the 12 V source is floating on one side, are you sure the - connection of V2 needs to be connected to the drain resistor? You **really** need to pay more attention to the details. Connect something to the MOSFET's gate, leaving it open is asking for trouble. The trouble with this question is that it is asked in such a confusing way that we have no idea what's going on but **if** you would have asked the question properly in a consistent way, it can be answered in **two** sentences.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I didn't find the VCC voltage thing, you know, like in the previous circuit.

Comment: *the VCC voltage thing* Then go look at schematics, type "MOSFET circuit" in Google search and press the images tab. Look at how circuits are drawn. Which ones are clear, which ones are not. Re-draw your circuit to resemble the clear ones. (you really should already know that the "VCC voltage thing" is a DC voltage source with one connection to a ground symbol, before you ask about MOSFETs). Leaving because you need way to much "hand-holding".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I literally did that. That circuit I linked to in the post was exactly the same as the one in the book. But you all said that it's not clear(For some reason I don't understand) and I now re-designed it again.

Answer (score 2):

Now there's a proper schematic and you have clarified that R = 1.25 ohms is the load, outside the FET...

yes, if you have reported accurately, the book has made a mistake. Vds = Id * Rds(on) = 2V.

I refer you to my other comment : Get Horowitz & Hill "The Art of Electronics" and make that your book instead.

Comment: It's actually my school's subject so I can't change my book but thank you so much. Just another question if you don't mind, is VDS(max) calculated the same as normal VDS?

Comment: That question needs context. My interpretation of it here : What would Vds be if the gate voltage was changed such that Id was 0? In other contexts it may mean the maximum Vds that the transistor can withstand without failing. You don't calculate that : the datasheet tells you that. Oh, and get a book you can rely on anyway. Use it alongside your school's text.

Comment: Oh so I don't calculate any of maximum ratings, right? They are given to me, right?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on context. Vds(max) of a transistor is given in its datasheet. Vds(max) of transistor M2 in you schematic has to be calculated (but it's a trivial calculation with Id=0). Compare your calculated value with the datasheet : if yours is higher, expect the transistor to die.

Comment: Doesn't that mean VDS(max) would be 0? Since VDS = Rdson x Id. And Id = 0(Like you said)

Comment: Of course not. "What would Vds be if the gate voltage was changed such that Id was 0". When the transistor is cut off, Rds(on) is irrelevant. What voltage is across R when Id=0?